# Removing MEGA 2560 and going straight from pc to stm robot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My school made a custom stm board and they gave me the codes for the stm imported it. But now, they also gave me the node file for ROS, how do I "install" the node? I'm very new at this any advice would help. thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252462/removing-mega-2560-and-going-straight-from-pc-to-stm-robot./) by [Acecryz](https://answers.ros.org/users/28951/acecryz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Acecryz](https://answers.ros.org/users/28951/acecryz/) on 2017-01-22**:
UPDATE : the guy who made the node gave the entire catwin_ws file but all I want is the node that makes motor controls work without the MEGA 2560.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Acecryz,

That's a pretty broad question and depending on your experience and/or knowledge of ROS, the answer widely varies.

If you're new to ROS. It would probably be a good idea to start with learning a little bit about ROS, for instance by looking at the [ROS Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials). The first tutorial deals with setting up your environment and a workspace, which you will need to compile and run the nodes.

For a more thorough introduction a book might be easier, several are listed at the ROS wiki over [here](http://wiki.ros.org/Books). This includes both free and paid books.

As a last piece of advice, you have a better chance of getting a satisfactorily answer if your question is a little more specific, and also include what you already know and have tried yourself.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0